# Feed Me - feed format for importing into Super Table field

Tags: craft3, plugin-feedme

I am trying to import a list with the following format in each list item: 
`<Date> - <Title> - <Icon> - <External Link>`
into a Super Table block containing fields for each of the above.

I tried with different xml formats following the documentation, but did not have any success importing multiple rows in the same Super Table field.

I wish to have it as:

**SuperTable field:**

```
<Date> - <Title> - <Icon> - <External Link>
<Date> - <Title> - <Icon> - <External Link>
<Date> - <Title> - <Icon> - <External Link>
```

But it creates a new Super Table entry with just a single row for the new list item each time.

i.e.

**SuperTable field:**

```
<Date> - <Title> - <Icon> - <External Link>
```

**SuperTable field:**

```
<Date> - <Title> - <Icon> - <External Link>
```

**SuperTable field:**

```
<Date> - <Title> - <Icon> - <External Link>
```

My current xml format is:

```
<entries>
  <entry>
    <SuperTable>
      <Row>
        <date><![CDATA[1583366400]]></date>
        <content><![CDATA[<strong>Some text here</strong>]]></content>
        <icon><![CDATA[]]></icon>
        <link><![CDATA[https://www.google.com]]></link>

      </Row>

      <Row>
        <date><![CDATA[1557273600]]></date>
        <content><![CDATA[Some more text for second item]]></content>
        <icon><![CDATA[]]></icon>
        <link><![CDATA[https://www.facebook.com]]></link>
      </Row>
    </SuperTable>
  </entry>
</entries>
```

Anyone could please point me to the right direction?

Comment: make sure your Primary element in step two of feed creation is /entries/entry not /entries **edit:** it seems this is related to an issue when feedme doesn't work as expected when supertable is inside matrix.
[https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/470#issuecomment-502378093](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/470#issuecomment-502378093)

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried it with /entries/entry, /entries/entry/SuperTable, /entries/entry/SuperTable/Row without any success.

Comment: sorry. i edited a long answer. this should have been a comment. although i tested your exact xml with feedme. when i choose entries as primary, i get one record , if i choose /entries/entry, i get both of them.  is this your original xml?

Comment: also is title of entry mapped to another xml element or what?

Comment: I’m trying to map just one field in an existing entry. I do that by using a particular ID for the entryID field. My title field therefore already is filled so I select do not map. So basically I’m not trying to create a new entry. My backend in this entry looks like:

- title 
- Lots of Other fields
- Super table field (subfields: date, text, url)

Comment: to make sure we're on the same page, if there is only one entry with three supertable item in xml, how the output looks like? - one supertable which have only one item or one supertable with three items, or three items in three different blocks? also what is supertable layout in field setting?

Comment: hey thanks for bearing with me! So if there is only one entry with 3 items in xml, the output (i.e. in the backend) looks like three items in three different blocks (one item in each block). I am trying to achieve these three within one single block because the list items belong to type of block which will later have one heading and the items under it.

Comment: go to field settings and edit your supertable field. Field Layout of super table field is probably Matrix Layout -as a result you see different block per item -. change this setting to table layout or row layout, now all of these items are in one block. but if you want another field for that block not whole entry, i guess maybe you need another solution. you need a matrix field with two fields: the supertable field and one text plain field for title, another fields are possible with this scenario. fortunately feedme supports supertable in matrix.

Comment: although your final solution depends on what exactly you need. let me know if you have further question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108543/discussion-between-zarun-and-user677900).